# Views filters on exposed block - Not working initially

Tags: views

I have a view with exposed filters "status" already set default to "ready".
The view filters are exposed in a block.

When I first open the view page, the status "ready" is ignored and it only applies the filter when I click on the "Submit" button in the exposed form.

I want the status "ready" to be applied when I open the view page.
This works great if the filters are not in an exposed block... but I need them to be...

What can I do?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar issue. Apply/Reset does not work initially but it starts to work when I use the pagination. I typed this in console (`Drupal.views.instances`) and noticed that `exposedAjaxForm` is missing initially.

Answer (score 0):

Download and enable [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters).
You should find a new setting under Exposed Form, in BEF Settings check "Autosubmit" and that might solve your problem. [image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Autosubmit is not a solution, I really need the submit button.